# Anchor sometimes jumps away randomly

Tags: azure-spatial-anchors

I am using Azure Spatial Anchor on Android(Unity), I found that when you locate an saved anchor, sometimes the anchor doesn't appear at the original position, when this problem occurs, it's like not only the anchor but the whole coordinate system is somehow 'rotated'.

e.g.
This is how it should be:
[image]

This is how it looks when it 'jumps away'.
[image]

I am not sure if this is caused by ARCore or Azure spatial anchor locating. No matter what is the root-cause, I need to avoid it. Please anyone give me some hint that how we can avoid this situation?

Comment: Hi are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Yes I do. Any comments, please?